# Pandas dataframe, how can I group by single column and apply sum to multiple column and add new sum column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This should be an easy one, but somehow I couldn't find a solution that works.

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Slno   Date         col2   col3   col4   col5  col6
0     01/02/20      2      1      2      5     d
1     03/02/20      5      1      2      4     g
2     04/02/20      5      1      2      5     h
3     05/02/20      4      1      2      6     e
4     08/02/20      8      1      2      5     g
5     05/02/20      8      1      2      8     r
```

**I want to group by Date and get the `sum()` of col2, col3, col4, col5 row wise as new column Total

Here is what I tried:

```
df_new[Total] = df.groupby(['Date', sort=False])["col2", "col3", col4", "col5].sum(axis = 1)
```

It gives ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

also I have tried

```
         df = (df.groupby(['Date'])
         .agg(Total=('ConfirmedIndianNational', 'ConfirmedForeignNational', 'Cured', 'Deaths', 'sum'))
         .reset_index())
```

It gives TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

I am new python, searched all the possible solution but of new use.

Comment: do you have duplicate dates? why do you groupby?

Comment: Yes, I do have duplicate dates @anky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `Date` as index then take sum of the columns on axis=1, then groupby `level=0` and transform `sum`

```
df['Total'] = (df.set_index('Date')[["col2", "col3","col4", "col5"]].sum(1)
           .groupby(level=0).transform('sum').to_numpy())
```

---

```
print(df)

   Slno      Date  col2  col3  col4  col5 col6  Total
0     0  01/02/20     2     1     2     5    d     10
1     1  03/02/20     5     1     2     4    g     12
2     2  04/02/20     5     1     2     5    h     13
3     3  05/02/20     4     1     2     6    e     32 # this is duplicated per group
4     4  08/02/20     8     1     2     5    g     16
5     5  05/02/20     8     1     2     8    r     32 # this is duplicated per group
```

Comment: @NadeemHaque Glad i could help. Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear is you have multiple values per date. If that is the case, your group by should aggregate that column by what ever function you want and the perform the sum of the rows with the aggregation.

For example you want the max value for each column per date:

```
max_df = df.groupby('Date')(['Date'])["col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"].max()
```

then:

```
max_df.loc[:,'sum_cols'] = max_df[["col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]].sum(axis = 1)
```

If you only have one row per date, you can do:

```
df.loc[:,'sum_cols'] = df[["col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]].sum(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a simple :

```
df[Total] = df.groupby(['Date').col1.sum()+df.groupby(['Date').col2.sum()+df.groupby(['Date').col3.sum()+df.groupby(['Date').col4.sum()
```

It should be ok.